# Efficient way to construct datetime64 and pandas time series?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

The time series index in `pandas` uses `numpy` `datetime64` type.

Is there any efficient way to construct `datetime64` objects?

The only ways I have seen on documents are either from a `string` or from a python `datetime` object.

If I have a large number of time stamps (millions), represented in epoch time (in terms of seconds from 1970-01-01), or nano sec epoch time (number of ns from 1970-01-01), is there any fast way to convert the integer to `numpy` `datetime64`?

Internally `numpy.datetime64` is also represented in integers.

I do not want to convert epoch time to string or python datetime object then convert to `numpy.datetime64`, since it is too inefficient for large amount of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pd.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#epoch-timestamps) will convert epoch timestamps as documented in the link:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime([1349720105, 1349806505, 1349892905,
         1349979305, 1350065705], unit='s')

print(dt)
DatetimeIndex(['2012-10-08 18:15:05', '2012-10-09 18:15:05',
           '2012-10-10 18:15:05', '2012-10-11 18:15:05',
           '2012-10-12 18:15:05'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for, it is extremely fast when pass ns epoch time! It is simply a astype('datetime64[ns]')

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is one. However I haven't measure the performance. According to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html

```
import numpy as np
a = np.datetime64('1970-01-01') + np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

or

```
a = np.datetime64('1970-01-01') + np.timedelta64(100, 'ns')
```